# Solving method of DLL crackme

Tags: ida, dll, crackme

I was given two DLL files [(link)](https://mega.nz/#!w0RnhJTQ!_j3sImHX2Heo0Zb35rZw6uKYLFz8FTqoSmnE-zZDrVs) . The task is to get the flag from them. First what I've done - opened the first file (called `original`) in IDA and found the function called `_GetFlag`.
[image]

As I understood, I need to call that function from the DLL library somehow (that's the first question - I don't have any info about the function except its name, so I'd like to know how exactly I can call it).
However, as wee see, even if I knew how to call it, we can't get the flag from `original` DLL, it says `Sry, flag is in the patched version`.

Ok, I opened `patched` DLL in IDA. First what we see that the file can be opened only as a binary:
[image]

As always, I opened the Strings window and we see the string `"0day is bring your own header day! Flag is: %s"` . It looks like a key for solution.

[image]

However, I don't exactly know what to do after that. I'd really appreciate if somebody would explain me how to solve this.

Comment: This might give you a hint https://imgur.com/FELroA0 The patched file has been changed to not look like a dll. Patch the bytes properly so that it is a valid dll.

Comment: @sudhackar thank you for your answer - I thought about it. Indeed, after I patched file signatures to MZ and PE it looks like a valid DLL. I see a functions like genFlag and getFlag - this is exactly what I need to call. What's the proper way to do that if we have only DLL file, in your opinion?

Comment: @kekyc: try LoadLibrary & GetProcAddress

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Yep, it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have patched the malformed bytes to make the patched DLL proper, you can use something like [this](https://gist.github.com/sudhackar/4f6b72092b88d4b11996475c679486de) to call the `GetFlag` function.

```
#include <Windows.h>

typedef DWORD (__cdecl *_GetFlag)();
_GetFlag GetFlag;
HMODULE hDll = NULL;

NTSTATUS main(int argc, char **argv) {
    hDll = LoadLibrary("my_head_flew_away_patched.dll");
    GetFlag = (_GetFlag)GetProcAddress(hDll, "GetFlag");
    GetFlag();
}
```

Comment: You late just for ~2-3 minutes I did it myself using the same method. But thank you, anyway!

Comment: If you look at the time of the gist, it is about the same time as the earlier comment. I didn't want to spoil it for you. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Of course, I understand that.